# WCF Multiple ConnectionStrings depending on recieved data

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a WCF Application that updates a database when it recieves data from a HttpWebResponse.

I want to have multiple databases connection strings in the web config file and depending on the response from the HttpWebResponse put data into correct database. All databases have identical tables.

IE if I send HttpWebResponse (111Hello) then put data into database named 111, (222Hello) the database named 222.

I have created a partial class to get the connection string from the web config file but am struggling to find out how I can make that programable.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you using entity framework?

Comment: What are you asking? What have you tried? This should be as easy as a switch statement that returns the correct connection string depending on the response.

Comment: Im using Linq to SQL, Where would I implement the switch statement? I'm very new to WCF (normally a vb application programmer)

Comment: Would I put the Switch in my service.svc.cs code?

Answer (score 2):

You need a `Repository` class, yhat has a connection string in constructor.

```
internal class Repository {
    public Repository(string connection string)
    {
       _connectionString = connectionString;
    }

    public int GetSomeEntityCount()
    {
        // your code
    }
}
```

Create Repositotory when you need to do smth with database

```
var repo = new Repository(connectionStringFromConfig);
```